How can I control sudden drop in battery voltage while connecting a motor
I have a 12V 45AH battery connected with 800W DC motor . When I switch ON a sudden drop in battery voltage. Do I need to use some device in between

Are you trying to solve a specific problem? Are you worried about something?

Sounds like you are looking for a DC motor soft start circuit, perhaps...?

When I switch ON a sudden drop in battery voltage and then what happens? Does the motor run? Smoke? What?

Batteries have an internal resistance.  You are seeing the voltage drop across that resistance due to the motor current.  A battery with a higher Ah rating, or one designed for motor starting will have a lower internal resistance, so should show a lower voltage drop when starting your motor.

You need to furnish more details to get a useful answer. How are you 'switching on' the motor? Does the motor run? What is the cable size? Is it a series or a shunt motor? Is it an automotive starter motor by any chance?
